# How to change font weight in React Native debugger?

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I'm trying to change the font weight of a text element in React Native Debugger (https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger).

I know font weight expects a *string* such as "300" or "500" (string's literal value itself should be without the quotes, but still a string, not a number). When I type `300` without quotation marks, it complains about expecting a string but getting a number. When I type `"300"` (with the quotes) then it complains that the value is invalid and it should be one of the values (100 to 900, bold, or normal) without the quotes (but when I enter it without quotes it parses it as a number, not a string).

What am I doing wrong?